# Horror movie about prisoners encountering Christian cannibals

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

It is about a few prisoners that are transported in a small van in to the country side, they managed to let the van stop and kill the cops with a big rock on his head (you see a dent in the head I remember)

After this they find a small wooden house in the mountains on a grassy area (not in dense woods). There is a Christian family in the house that are cannibals and try to eat/kill the prisoners.  They had a cross above their door. They invited the prisoners in and made them comfortable, but turned cannibalistic on them.

I saw this movie around 2007 on DVD. I think it is American but I'm not sure.

I have no idea of the name. It is **not** one of the following:

- Wrong Turn 3
- House of 1000 Corpses
- The Hills Have Eyes

If you found a possible title I might be wrong because some parts are faded or I mixed up another movie. But the most important is that wooden house in the mountain area with some cannibals living in it.

Comment: Maybe they are more like zombies than cannibals

Comment: Is it The Devil's Rejects?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Nah, doesn't really fit.

Answer (score 6):

[Chain Reaction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460742/) (AKA *House of Blood* AKA *House of Horrors*) from 2006 contains most of these elements, right up to the vague demonic nature of the cannibal family attacking the escaped convicts in the cabin. They seem to be more like zombies, or vampires.

> A group of convicts and a doctor seek refuge from the authorities in a lodge deep in the wood, but the weird inhabitants are not friendly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of a scene from Judge Dredd:

> Dredd finds himself seated next to Herman Ferguson on a transport ship
>   to the Aspen penal colony. While passing over the Cursed Earth the
>   ship is shot down by the Angel Gang, a family of cannibalistic
>   scavengers who capture Dredd and Herman. A squad of Judges tracks
>   Dredd to the Angels' camp and a battle ensues. Fargo arrives just in
>   time to save Dredd's life, but is mortally wounded by Mean Machine
>   Angel (Chris Adamson). Before dying, Fargo reveals the secrets of
>   Dredd's past.

The family claimed to be christian and cannbalistic, if I remember correctly.